# Behaviour Difference: Intellij vs Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to import and run existing and working Java code into Intellij but I ran into few problems and this causes me to write this question here:

My Storm topology (java) code is reading data from Websphere MQ and the recieved message which is a byte-stream and parsed by a "Message Parser" project; it parses these bytestream "String" and generates meaningful message based on some rules.

When I run it in Eclipse it works without any issue, but in Intellij it shows me problem related to message parser. I senses it as encoding issue and tried to:

- Change the code file encoding to UTF-8
- Change line separator to become identical (Unix)

But this did not lead me to resolution.

Because you all have good expertise in Java IDEs, hence I expect you must have faced the IDE's compatibility issues for Java code many of the times.
Kindly let me know if there is any way to resolve this problem.

The code where the problem is occuring is given below:

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {

    String strMessage = null;
    Message posMsg = null;
                Object jmsMsg = input.getValueByField(FieldEnum.FIELD_MESSAGE
                .getFieldName());
        posMsg = ((JMSMessage) jmsMsg);
        strMessage = convertStreamToString(posMsg);

        System.out.println("Message recieved from MQ : "+ strMessage);

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map parsedSegments = MessageParser.instance().parseMessage(
                strMessage);

        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        Type nposMessageType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {
        }.getType();
        String segmentsJson = gson.toJson(parsedSegments, nposMessageType);

        System.out.println(" testing the messages "+segmentsJson);
MessageDetail MessageDetail = new MessageDetail(
                Constant.TOPOLOGY_NAME, segmentsJson);
        this.outputCollector.emit(Constant.STREAM_MSG_PARSER_SUCCESS,
                new Values(MessageDetail));
        this.outputCollector.ack(input);
}


        /**
 * Convert stream to string
 * 
 * @param jmsMsg
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static String convertStreamToString(final Message jmsMsg) throws Exception {
    String stringMessage = "";
    BytesMessage bMsg = (BytesMessage) jmsMsg;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[40620];
    int byteRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((byteRead = bMsg.readBytes(buffer)) != -1) {
        bout.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
    }
    bout.flush();
    stringMessage = new String(bout.toByteArray());
    bout.close();
    return stringMessage;
}
```

Comment: It'S going to be hard to tell you what's wrong if we don't know what the problem IntelliJ is showing you is.

Comment: @Dragondraikk As I said: Intellij is facing problem to parse the message which is recieved from MQ, while Eclipse parses it.

Comment: Surely it gives you a specific error message? It would be helpful to have that in your question.

Comment: This message is bytestream string, and there is a module "Message parser" which parses this message...

Comment: IntelliJ and Eclipse don't receive any message from MQ. Your code is. Post your code, and tell us precisely **what** the problem is, including complete error messages, stack traces, expected and observed behavior.

Comment: @JBNizet Posted the code.. The issue is in Intellij if parses the message wrongly... I mean it shows no issue but the parsed message it incorrect...

Comment: Most likely your run configurations are different. One of them is passing correct encoding flags. Other one is not.

Comment: @Jayan.. thanks for your suggestion, same I sensed but do we have any workarounds to solve this.

Comment: @tom:  Why don't you _try_ and let us know?   You need to fix your configuration not a work around..

Answer (score 2):

Your code is to blame. You're using

```
new String(bout.toByteArray());
```

to convert bytes to characters. That uses the platform default encoding. It's different when running from Eclipse than it is when running with IntelliJ, because IntelliJ, if I'm not mistaken, passes a JVM option forcing the default encoding to UTF-8.

But that's not an IntelliJ problem. Your code would fail the same way if you were running your program out of any IDE, on a platform whose default encoding is UTF-8 (Linuxes and Macs, for example).

Every time you transform bytes into chars and vice-versa, make sure to specify an encoding explicitely. If MQ is generating the message, read its documentation to know which encoding it uses, and make sure to use the same one. For example, if it's ISO-8859-1, use

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am changing the logic to parse the MQ message and to become platform independent.

Comment: I tried to give ISO_8859_1 while converting the ByteStream into String, Again.. it worked in Eclipse but not in Intellij.. I set the File Encoding, project encoding etc in Intellij as ISO_8859_1 but no advantage... 
Could you suggest anything else which may be root cause for this?

Comment: Don't blindly use ISO_8859_1. That's an example. You need to **know** what encoding is used when transforming the String to bytes, and use the same when transforming the bytes to String.

Comment: Actually its ISO_8859_1, which is used when pushing data into MQ. Thats why I have used it, not because of the example. Still Intellij is declining it..dont know why!

Comment: What do you mean by "declining"? what happens? What is the original string, the received byte array and the transformed string?